# Flymake stopped working with elpy...no idea what I did or didn't do [Windows]

Tags: microsoft-windows, elpy, flymake

I installed elpy, along with jedi, rope and got it to work briefly yesterday after uninstalling python and reinstalling it with anaconda and setting the environment variable to path. I tinkered around yesterday both with the emacs config files and trying to setup virtualenvs.

Here is my elpy config:

```
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 26.3
Elpy..............: 1.34.0
Virtualenv........: env (c:/Users/Robby Parliament/python-virtual-environments/env/)
Interactive Python: python 38 (c:/Users/Robby Parliament/python-virtual-environments/env/Scripts/python.exe)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (c:/Users/Robby Parliament/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/pythonw.exe 3.8.3 (c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/pythonw.exe)
 Jedi.............: 0.17.1
 Rope.............: 0.17.0
 Autopep8.........: 1.5.3
 Yapf.............: 0.30.0
 Black............: Not found
Syntax checker....: flake8.exe (c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/flake8.exe)

Warnings

Elpy could not connect to Pypi (or at least not quickly enough) and
check if the python packages were up-to-date. You can still try to
update all of them:

[Update python packages]

Pip doesn't seem to be installed in the dedicated virtualenv created
by Elpy (c:/Users/Robby Parliament/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv). This may
prevent some features from working properly (completion,
documentation, reformatting, ...). You can try reinstalling the
virtualenv. If the problem persists, please report on Elpy's github
page.

[Reinstall RPC virtualenv]

The black package is not available. Commands using this will not work.

[Install black]

Options

`Raised' text indicates buttons; type RET or click mouse-1 on a button
to invoke its action.  Invoke [+] to expand a group, and [-] to
collapse an expanded group.  Invoke the [Group], [Face], and [Option]
buttons below to edit that item in another window.
```

I get two errors when I try to do a syntax check on my `test.py` sieve algorithm (below):

```
1. MAX_PRIME = 100
2. sieve = [True] * MAX_PRIME
3. for i as range(2, MAX_PRIME):
4.   if sieve[i]:
5.        print(i)
6.            for j in range(i * i, MAX_PRIME, i):
7.                sieve[j] = False
```

The third line should be highlighted under `as` seeing as it's incorrect syntax. It picked up yesterday but not anymore. The two errors are as follows:

```
Warning [flymake test.py]: Disabling backend python-flymake because 
(file-error Spawning child process Exec format error)
Warning [flymake test.py]: Disabling backend flymake-proc-legacy-flymake because 
(error Can’t find a suitable init function)
```

Comment: not sure if you ever figured this out. I was debugging similar things over the weekend and discovered that elpy isn't really all that involved in flymake. Looing at the `elpy.el` source code: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/blob/4248dccef31e260813d93cafd083bfcd71efc92a/elpy.el#L3668-L3673 it turns out it's using flymake directly.

From there I discovered that `python-flymake-command` needs to read from stdin, and you may need to adjust `python-flymake-command-output-pattern`.